# scoping issues in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, scoping

I have a service that returns an array.

```
main(){ 
    this.addressService.getState().subscribe( (data:any)=>{
          this.usStates = data;
          if(this.usStates.length===0) {
            this.notificationService.showErrorNotification('Unable to get states');
console.log(this.usStates); //length of array is 10
          }
        });
console.log(this.usStates); //empty array
}
```

How can I get the updated value of `this.usStates` outside the scope of callback?

Comment: If you want to do anything with your usStates variable, you should do that in the subscribe to be sure it is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is by itself correct. This is purely a timing issue. The problem is that the second `console.log(this.usStates);` which is outside of the subscription is executed immediately - and in that case the `this.usStates` array is still empty. Basically the following is happening:

[image]

So outside of the subscribe function, you just need to check for the existence of the value. Something like this:

```
if (this.usStates.length>0) { console.log(...) }
```

Or if you are binding to the data, you need to use `*ngIf` or the safe navigation operator (?).